# how to convert date time to local user specific time zone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have this timezone saved in my mysql database without any timezone added in it.

```
date: 2021-04-10 15:04:11 (UTC)
```

So I am using a get api to get from the database and showing on my react component using below code.

```
<div>moment(date).tz(moment.tz.guess()).format("MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm A")</div>
```

Now using the above code it shows my same date as above `2021-04-10 15:04:11 (UTC)` on the browser. But I need it in my local timezone "America/New_York"... How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I generate a utc moment date with your `date` and after I formatted .

```
const utcDate = moment.utc('2021-04-10 15:04:11');
console.log(utcDate);
console.log(moment.tz.guess());
const dateInMyTz = moment(utcDate).tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('MMMM DD, YYYY HH:mm A');
console.log(dateInMyTz);
```

this is the console result:

```
Moment<2021-04-10T15:04:11Z>
Europe/Rome
aprile 10, 2021 17:04 PM
```